# Neo4j create ranking by region by vendor based on similarity

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, cql

I am able to create recommendation with materials not bought by user using materials in common(similarity) and showed as recommendation engine

```
MATCH (eid:eid{id:'102'})-[:BOUGHT]->(mat:material)<-[:BOUGHT]-(someOthereid:eid)-[:BOUGHT]->(m2:material)
WHERE
    NOT((eid)-[:BOUGHT]->(m2))
    AND eid <> someOthereid
RETURN distinct m2,eid
```

and recommendation based ranking by location by vendor irrespective of similarity (recommends all materials excluding own)

```
match (n:bookdb)
match (m:material{id:n.mat}) match(eid:eid{id:'104'}) match(ecl:ecountry{id:n.eloc}) 
match(ven:vendor{id:n.ven}) match(vloc:vlocation{id:n.vloc})  
WHERE NOT (m)<-[:BOUGHT]-(eid)
with distinct eid, m,count(m) as timessold,ven,vloc
return  distinct eid,m,timessold,ven,vloc  order by timessold desc,m
```

but unable to create one query using both first and second query ,create ranking by location by vendor with respective to similarity (as in first query). Please suggest..

I am expecting recommendation on similar materials bought by ranking group by vendor by region

I am adding sample data

[image]

and my result should be like it should first show me by ranking of number of times material bought with respect to vendor location and vendor i.e. ORDER BY timessold desc,vlocation,vendor. I am getting result but ranking is not working with respect to vlocation and vendor

my expected result should be .. lets consider enduserid=104 then result should be like below scheenshot.. material recommended)excluding material enduserid already bought) order by vendor,vendorlocation here timessold is number of times material sold by vendor from vendorlocation to enduserid

[image]

and if we consider enduserid=106 then no material should get recommended as there is no material in common

Comment: What exactly is `timessold` supposed to represent?

Comment: number of times the material sold by vendor to enduser

Comment: In your sample data, why are the `endUserId` and `vendorloc` columns identical? Also, can you show what the result should be for the sample data?

Comment: @cybersam here vendorloc is imp so I copied same to enduserloc.. my expected result added in question. you can ignore enduserloc(its not enduserid)..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UNION` statement to join the results of two queries. You have to be careful that both queries return the same columns. You can also do post-UNION processing. Here is an example from the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/post-union-processing/):

```
MATCH (m:Movie {title:'The Matrix'})
CALL {
    WITH m
    MATCH (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p)
    RETURN p
    UNION
    WITH m
    MATCH (m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(p)
    RETURN p
}
RETURN p.name as name
ORDER BY name ASC
```

This syntax will only work in Neo4j 4.0 and forward.

Comment: I am expecting similarity based recommendation on ranking by region by vendor

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
MATCH (eid:eid)-[:BOUGHT]->(:material)<-[:BOUGHT]-(otherEid:eid)
WHERE eid.id = '104' AND eid <> otherEid
WITH DISTINCT eid, otherEid
MATCH (otherEid)-[:BOUGHT]->(m:material)
WHERE NOT (eid)-[:BOUGHT]->(m)
WITH eid, m, COUNT(*) AS timessold
MATCH (n:bookdb), (ecl:ecountry), (ven:vendor), (vloc:vlocation) 
WHERE n.mat = m.id AND ecl.id = n.eloc AND ven.id = n.ven AND vloc.id = n.vloc
RETURN eid, m, timessold, ecl, ven, vloc
ORDER BY timessold DESC, m
```

Comment: @cybersam..thank you but it is not working  , result is showing rank with respect to materials bought not by region by vendor

Comment: So, I see you added that requirement to your question. What do you mean by "region"?

Comment: I am expecting recommendation on similar materials bought by ranking group by vendor by region-
here by region means by country/location

Comment: And you no longer care about ordering by `timessold`?

Comment: my goal is to recommend materials based on similarity Order by rank(timessold) by country(vendor country-vcountry) by vendor

Comment: You can [add more terms](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.1/clauses/order-by/#order-nodes-by-multiple-properties) (e.g., `vendor`) to the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I tried but its not working . Ranking is not showing properly as there is not straight relationship created between recommended materials and vendor and country to do order by and I cant create relationship as it makes graph model uneven.. Thank you for taking time and responding to my request.. I am newbie to Cypher, learning now and surfing entire google to sort this out..

Comment: Can you add to your question some sample data and an example of the kind of result you want?

Comment: I am unable to add here so edited my question and added there.. thank you.